# Array of check box answers correct r not (condition)

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Who to check array of check box answers correct or not?

For example

- 4 options are A, B, C, D
- answers are [true, false, true, true]

My logic

```js
var isCorrect;

for(i=0; i>options.length; i++) {
    if(option[i] == true ) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the (>) to (<) and also spelling mistake loop condition spelling (options) and if condition spelling (option)

**BEFORE**

```
var isCorrect;
    
    for(i=0; i > options.length; i++) {
        if(option[i] == true ) {
    
        }
    }
```

**AFTER**

```
var isCorrect;

    for(i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if(options[i] == true ) {
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, use `every` method to check each option with corresponding answer

```js
const checkAnswers = (options, answers) =>
  options.every((option, i) => option === answers[i]);


const options1 = [true, false, true, true];
const ans1 = [true, false, true, true];
console.log(checkAnswers(options1, ans1));

const options2 = [false, false, true, true];
const ans2 = [true, false, true, true];
console.log(checkAnswers(options2, ans2));
```